# Wt C++ - adding GET values to the URL

Tags: c++, get, wt

Am I able to add GET values to the URL in witty library, like: www.somewebsite.com?SomeSuperValue=12&other=something ?

Comment: WT is a server side library; in order to compose a GET URI you would need a client side one.

Comment: No, wt makes "application", which sends layout to the user and everything else is happening on the server side (changes are of course send to the user by ajax or something). I know how to change path (function Wt::WApplication::setInternalPath() or WLink class), but I cannot add there GET values (only add /some/string/with/slashes). I can of course split that string, but I thought there is already implemented some code, that handles GET variables.

Comment: interesting question. You should rather ask it on Wt mailing list, it has more Wt users than on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I never tried but I think this might do it:

```
#include <Wt/WEnvironment>

const WEnvironment& env = WApplication::instance()->environment();
   ...
 // read an application startup argument 
 // (passed as argument in the URL or POST'ed to the application).
 if (!env.getParameterValues("login").empty())
 {
   std::string login = env.getParameterValues("login")[0];
 }
```

you also have the WEnvironment& env as a parameter of the WApplication class overload, if you use c++.

EDIT: I just tested it and it works!